# Array Binding Parameter Using DbCommand

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, dbconnection

I'm trying to bind an array to insert data to a table in a bulk operation using a DbCommand.

I can do this using an `OracleCommand` (and hence also using a `OracleConnection`) using:

```
    var referenceValues = validRecords.Select(x => x.Reference).ToArray<string>();
    var fundDescriptionValues = validRecords.Select(x => x.FundDescription).ToArray<string>();
    var fundCodeValues = validRecords.Select(x => x.FundCode).ToArray<string>();

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    OracleParameter referenceParam = new OracleParameter
    {
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value = referenceValues
    };

    OracleParameter fundDescriptionParam = new OracleParameter
    {
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value = fundDescriptionValues
    };

    OracleParameter fundCodeParam = new OracleParameter
    {
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value = fundCodeValues
    };

    OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"
                INSERT INTO FUND_IMPORT
                (
                    REFERENCE,
                    FUND_DESCRIPTION,
                    FUND_CODE
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    :1,
                    :2,
                    :3
                )";

    cmd.ArrayBindCount = referenceValues.Length;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(referenceParam);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(fundDescriptionParam);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(fundCodeParam);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
```

Is there a way to do this type of operation using a `DbCommand` (and hence also using a `DbConnection`)?

We are migrating to SQL Server instead of Oracle but I would still prefer to use a Generic library rather than `SQLCommand`.

Comment: No, there is just no operation in SQL to insert this in one Command. You have to iterate the array and insert one by one. The parameterized command is a good approach.

Comment: @Holger so this feature is unique to the OracleCommand library? Is there an equivalent in the SQLCommand library?

Comment: As more general you go, as smaller the common subset of commands. This smallest subset is ANSI-SQL. That has no bulk-inserts nor updates.
So as long as you just send Text-commands to the server, there is nothing specific to a certain SQL server. Any other communication, other than text, must be server specific. OracleCommand and SQLCommand are DbCommands !
DbCommand cannot be used, it's not a generalized thing, it's an abstract thing.
Today you rather do abstraction by ORM-Mapping, using things like Entity framework, that will generate alle the commands for you.